# Why can't I exclude this row based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ec1f/119

Here's my fiddle...I want the result to look like this but the query I'm using doesn't do that:

[image: img]

My problem with the query is that I can't seem to exclude "The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull" using the exclusion_flag condition. I also don't know why it seems that Contract 3 (Raiders of the Lost Arc) is not showing up either. I have been toiling with this for hours and have no idea what the problem is. I tried looking into subqueries, but I'm not sure that's the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of questions/issues there so I'll try to address them individually.

1) You can't exclude "The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull" using the exclusion_flag because contract_sid 7 and 8 both refer to product_list_sid 3 which includes "The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull" - you would need to create a separate product_list_sid if you wanted a contract which excluded it.

2) "Raiders of the Lost Arc" (contract_sid 3) isn't showing up because it's a "single product" contract, and your query only joins from scope to product_list_join using product_list_id - contract_sid 3 is in the product_sid column so you need a separate join to cater for contracts that use product_sid instead of product_list_sid (I assume that a contract can't use both). This is a pretty dodgy schema design but here's a query that solves that issue. Notice the use of LEFT OUTER JOIN to indicate that the table being joined to might not contain any rows (for example when scope.product_list_sid is NULL but scope.product_sid is not).

```
SELECT   s.contract_sid,
         c.contract_description,
         ISNULL(p.product_description, p2.product_description) AS product_description
FROM     scope s
JOIN     contracts c ON (c.contract_sid = s.contract_sid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
         product_list_join plj ON (plj.product_list_sid = s.product_list_sid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
         products p ON (p.product_sid = plj.product_sid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
         products p2 ON (p2.product_sid = s.product_sid)
WHERE    s.exclusion_flag = 'N'
ORDER BY s.contract_sid;
```

Here's the SQLFiddle for my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc62e/10

Edit: After posting this I realised what you're actually trying to do - the scope table not only provides the details of contracts but also provides specific products to exclude from contracts. Again, this is bad schema design and there should be a separate scope_exclusions table or something, but here's a query that does that and excludes "The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull" as requested:

```
SELECT   inner_query.contract_description,
         inner_query.product_description
FROM     (
         SELECT   s.contract_sid,
                  c.contract_description,
                  ISNULL(p.product_sid, p2.product_sid) AS product_sid,
                  ISNULL(p.product_description, p2.product_description) AS product_description
         FROM     scope s
         JOIN     contracts c ON (c.contract_sid = s.contract_sid)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  product_list_join plj ON (plj.product_list_sid = s.product_list_sid)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  products p ON (p.product_sid = plj.product_sid)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  products p2 ON (p2.product_sid = s.product_sid)
         WHERE    s.exclusion_flag = 'N'
         ) inner_query
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (   SELECT   1
                        FROM     scope
                        WHERE    exclusion_flag = 'Y'
                        AND      contract_sid = inner_query.contract_sid
                        AND      product_sid = inner_query.product_sid )
ORDER BY inner_query.contract_description;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc62e/14